# Divisors of a $ k $-multiperfect number

Tags: number-theory, perfect-numbers

Let  $ n $ be a $ k $-multiperfect number. Denote by  $ d_m $ its  $ m $ smallest divisor, and  $ n_{m} $ the number of divisors of  $ n $ divisible by  $ d_m $. Is there for all $ 2\leq m\leq\tau(n) $ an integer  $ s(m) $ such that  $ n_m=d_{s(m)} $? Does the function  $ s $ admit a fixed point ?

Edit : actually  $ n_{m}=\tau(n/d_{m}) $. A sufficient condition for a number  $ n $ to fulfill  $ d=\tau(n/d) $ is to take  $ n=\prod_{r}p_{r}^{p_{\sigma(r)}-1} $ with  $ \sigma $ a permutation of the set of primes  $ p $ such that  $v_{p}(n)\geq 1 $ and  $d=\prod_{p, v_{p}(n)\geq 1}p $ .

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe you could use a result in Dagal's [A Lower Bound for $\tau(n)$ of $k$-Multiperfect Number](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.3527.pdf)?